# How To Convert A Wiki Table To A Link?

Tags: hyperlink, html-table, mediawiki

The following HTML code displays a table which is a link to another site.  That is, clicking on any pixel in the inner table (even white space) invokes the link.  How do I code this in a Wiki using pipes syntax?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>How To Convert A Wiki Table To A Link?</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>

<body>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="20%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="http://google.com">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">M pigeons</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">000</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">into N holes</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```

Pipes Syntax for this table-in-a-table looks like this (but without the <a href="..."> ... </a>)

```
{| border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="20%" style="border-collapse: collapse;"
|
{| border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
|-
|style="text-align: left;"|M pigeons
|style="text-align: right;"|000
|-
|colspan="2"|into N holes
|}
|}
```

How do I achieve the effect of the <a href="..."> ... </a> as in the HTML code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell: you can do this with MediaWiki's external link syntax and a single-line HTML table, but it won't work if you have enabled HTML tidying.

### MediaWiki links

In MediaWiki, the default settings are to disallow `<a>...</a>` tags in wikitext. This is for security reasons: if your wiki is publicly editable and  `<a>...</a>` tags were allowed unchecked, anyone could add arbitrary JavaScript to your site, by adding links like `<a onmouseover="alert(1)">foo</a>`.

Instead, you add links to wikitext in two different ways. For internal links to other pages on the same wiki, you use `[[Page name|display text]]`, which produces something like `<a href="/wiki/Page_name" class="mw-redirect" title="Page name">display text</a>`. For external links, you use `[http://www.example.com Example]`, which produces a link like `<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>`.

For what were probably Very Good Reasons At The Time, you can insert newline characters into the display text of internal links, but not external links. So this produces a valid link:

```
[[Page name|display
text]]
```

But this is just output as-is (with the URL itself linked):

```
[http://www.example.com display
text]
```

This will be important later on.

### MediaWiki tables

While MediaWiki doesn't allow `<a>...</a>` tags in wikitext, it does allow a subset of HTML tags. This includes `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<td>`, which means that there are actually two ways to make tables in wikitext. The first is using wikitext table syntax, like you have done in your question:

```
{|
| Row 1, cell 1
| Row 1, cell 2
|-
| Row 2, cell 1
| Row 2, cell 2
|}
```

The second is by using HTML table elements:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>Row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For wikitext table syntax, you need to add newline characters for the table to render properly. However, for HTML table tags, you can do everything on one line, like `<table><tr><td>Foo</td></tr></table>`.

### How to put tables in links

Putting a table inside a link in MediaWiki is a matter of putting the appropriate table syntax inside the appropriate link syntax. If your link is an internal link, you can choose either of the table syntaxes:

```
[[Page name|
{|
| Foo
|}
]]

[[Page name|
<table>
<tr>
<td>Foo</td>
</tr>
</table>
]]
```

These will both produce something like the following HTML:

```
<a href="/wiki/Page_name" class="mw-redirect" title="Page name">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Foo</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</a>
```

If your link is an external one, then because the external link syntax doesn't accept newline characters, you are limited to using HTML table tags.

```
[http://www.example.com <table><tr><td>Foo</td></tr></table>]
```

This will produce something like the following HTML:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.example.com">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Foo</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</a>
```

In your case, the following code should do what you are trying to do:

```
{| border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="20%" style="border-collapse: collapse;"
| [http://www.google.com <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td style="text-align: left;">M pigeons</td><td style="text-align: right;">000</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">into N holes</td></tr></table>]
|}
```

### Why you might not want to do this

While putting table tags inside links is allowed in HTML 5, it is not allowed in HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0. When I tested your HTML with the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org), it gave me the error 'document type does not allow element "table" here'.

I believe that more recent versions of MediaWiki use HTML 5, so this might not be an error per se. However, if your wiki uses HTML tidying software, then tables inside links might be interpreted as broken HTML, and "fixed" for you. When I tested the above code on Wikipedia, which I think currently uses the HTML 5 tidying algorithm, the link was rendered *before* the table.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="20%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
<td><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">M pigeons</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">into N holes</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So, if you really want to do this, then go ahead, but beware that there may be pitfalls.

One last thing: if you want to use `<a>` tags in wikitext as-is, it is possible to enable the [$wgRawHtml](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml) option. However, **do not** do this if your wiki is publicly editable! It will enable people to add random JavaScript to your site, which is Not A Good Idea.

Comment: Excellent description!  The links I needed to insert were all local, so your example of "How to put tables in links" was exactly what I needed.  Thanks very much for taking the time to provide such a detailed and readable answer.